# Comparing different datatypes in ML

Tags: ml

```
type Name = string;
datatype Expr = Const of int
    | Var of Name
    | Neg of Expr
    | Plus of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | App of Fun * Expr
    and Fun = Def of Name * Expr

(* substitute every x in expression z with expression y *)

fun substitute (Name x, Expr y, Expr z) = if x = z then y else z;
```

I just want to compare the string values of x and z and if they are the same return y, and otherwise return z, but I keep getting this error?

```
e.sml:13.33-13.39 Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: Expr
e.sml:13.25-13.31 Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: Expr
e.sml:13.17-13.23 Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: Name
e.sml:13.50 Error: unbound variable or constructor: z
e.sml:13.46 Error: unbound variable or constructor: x
e.sml:13.57 Error: unbound variable or constructor: y
e.sml:13.64 Error: unbound variable or constructor: z

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
         ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `substitute` doesn't make a hell lot of sense ;). First, you are using types and pattern matching wrong, and second you need to substitute recursively, not just the root expression.

Here is a sketch of a working version:

```
fun substitute(x, e, Const n)      = Const n
  | substitute(x, e, Var y)        = if x = y then e else Var y
  | substiture(x, e, Neg e')       = Neg(substitute(x, e, e'))
  | substitute(x, e, Plus(e1, e2)) = Plus(substitute(x, e, e1), substitute(x, e, e2))
  | ...
```

You should be able to fill in the remaining cases. The `App` case requires a bit of care to avoid accidental capturing in the function -- that is, you have to avoid substituting inside the body when `x` is the same as the parameter variable.

If you are keen on giving type annotations, then this function is perhaps best written with a case:

```
fun substitute(x : Name, e : Expr, z : Expr) =
    case z of
      Const n => z
    | Var y   => if x = y then e else z
    | Neg e'  => Neg(substitute(x, e, e'))
    ...
```

That's equivalent to the former, which is just syntactic sugar for a case.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that the syntax for function parameters is `typename variablename`. It's not. The syntax is `pattern : typename` or just `pattern` where the simplest form of a pattern is simply a variable name.

Writing things like `Name x` would imply that `Name` is a constructor of some datatype and that you're trying to pattern match your first argument (which must be a value of that datatype) against that constructor. That's not what you want.

To define a function that takes the arguments `x`, `y` and `z`, you should just write:

```
fun substitute (x, y, z) = ...
```

Or, if you want to spell out the types of parameters:

```
fun substitute (x: Name, y: Expr, z: Expr) = ...
```

PS: In the body of your function you write `x = z`, but that can't work because `x` and `z` are values of different types - they can't possibly be equal to each other.

Comment: But then how can I compare Name to Var, since they're both strings?

Comment: @Jay `"hello"` is a string. `Var "hello"` is *not* a string, it's a value of type `Expr`. If you have a value of type string (or `Name`, which is the same thing) and another value of type `Expr` and you want to check whether the `Expr` is a `Var` with the given name, then you have to use pattern matching to a) check that the `Expr` is indeed a `Var` and b) take the string out of the `Var`, so you can compare it with your other string. If that does not make sense to you, you should read up on how pattern matching works in ML.